# checkedlistbox pero solo me pasa el ultimo al datagridview

Tags: c#

Buenas tardes estoy tratando de pasar los datos capturados del `checkedlistbox` pero solo me pasa el ultimo al `datagridview`

En el `DataGridView` solo anexe la base de datos con el `datasource`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y este es mi código de alta

```
private void btnRegistrar_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     try
     {
          contexto = new checkListdbEntities3();

          rchecklist rchecklist = new rchecklist()
          {
               IDObra = int.Parse(txtid.Text),
               Obra=txtObra.Text,
               check=clbCheck.Text,
               Notas=txtnotas.Text,
               Novivienda=txtvivienda.Text,
               Residente=txtResidente.Text,
          };

          contexto.rchecklists.Add(rchecklist);
          contexto.SaveChanges();
          MessageBox.Show("Agregado Correctamente");
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
          MessageBox.Show("Ocurrio un Error no se registro ticket:" + ex.ToString());
     }
}
```

aquí no tengo ningún problema solo que cuando selecciono las opciones del `checkedlistbox` no me pasa todas solo la ultima.

Comment: No comprendo bien tu pregunta

Comment: Basicamente tengo unos textbox y esos los paso a mi base de datos asi como mi checkedlistbox  pero este tiene 4 opciones  y al momento de darle en el boton registrar me guarda todo, pero al momento de consultar el datagridview solo me muestra el ultimo campo seleccionado del checkedlistbox

Comment: Pero no veo en tu código el método que usas para consultar en el `DataGridView` puedes mostrarlo?

Comment: en el datagridview no tengo un metodo solo agregue la base de datos en el datasource la flechita que tiene en la parte superior izquierda y agregar base de datos.  y me agrega los datos capturados que anteriormente ya registre

Comment: Entonces le cambio la pregunta: El `DataSource` que le agrega via el diseñador al `DataGridView` tiene la misma estructura de campos que su `DataGridView`?

Comment: No, solo en mi base de datos tengo una tabla le inserto checklistobox y le asigno y en mi datagridview tengo solo la tabla check que es la que relaciona el checklist box.